# Let $A \in M_n(F[x])$ be an invertible matrix. Prove that $\deg(\det A)=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, alternative-proof

> Let  $A \in M_n(F[x])$ be an invertible matrix. Prove that $\deg(\det A)=0$

I succeeded proving it using $\det(AB)=\det A\det B$, without using the adjoint matrix like I was instructed to do.

I need your help proving it using that $A\cdot\mathrm{Adj}(A)=(\det A)I$.

Thank you!

Comment: Your approach with determinants is the most common approach. Is there any chance that you have misunderstood your assignment? Perhaps you are not supposed to prove it using the adjugate.

Comment: I don't think so because the question has the instruction written as it is to use the formula above.

Comment: The formula above could be transformed back into $A A^{-1} = I$ and then use the determinant formula. Are you sure they don't mean that? The other way I could think of is by concluding $det(Adj)=det(A)^{n-1}$ and then somehow convert it back into the determinant of cofactors and find the way out. Pretty hardcore to solve this to me. Does anyone else have a better idea?

Comment: I will add an answer once I get the solution from my teacher. Thank you!