# Proving $\deg(\det(A))=0$ given that there exists $B$ such that $AB=I$ where $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F[x])$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I noticed that [the very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624493/let-a-in-m-nfx-be-an-invertible-matrix-prove-that-deg-det-a-0) has been asked before, but has no answer to it, so I decided to ask anyway. I am instructed to prove this using $A\cdot\mathrm{Adj}(A)=(\det A)\cdot I$, but no matter how I tried to manipulate this, I don't know how to proceed. My progress so far is trivial.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This can be proved directly: since $AB=I$, we have $\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)=\det(I)=1$. Therefore $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ are units in the ring $\mathbb F[x]$ and $\deg(\det(A))=1$. I don't think the use of the adjugate matrix can make the proof easier.

Comment: @user1551 So I've heard read in the comments in the linked question. I suppose if the instruction makes matters more difficult there is no sense in using it then.